# Stored procedure output parameter returns @Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm struggling with this thing for the past hour and I'm sure I'm missing something small, I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 and C# code that I want to return the output parameters of my stored procedure.

SQL :

```
Alter Procedure dbo.GetAssessment
    @UserID int,
    @AssessmentName varchar(255),
    @Score varchar(100) output,
    @Completed varchar(10) output,
    @DisplayName nvarchar(128) output,
    @Result varchar(2500) output
as
begin
        select @Score = A.Score, @Completed = A.Completed, @DisplayName = U.Displayname, @Result = A.Result 
        from Assessment A 
            inner join Users U
            on U.UserId = A.UserID
        where U.UserID = @UserId
        and AssessmentName = @AssessmentName

end
GO
```

C#

```
String SScore, SName, SResult, SComp;
            lblAsse.Text = Request.QueryString["AID"];

            InsertAssessment(lblAsse.Text, "No", 2, "N/A", "N/A");

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlParameter outScore = new SqlParameter("@Score", SqlDbType.VarChar,100){ Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                SqlParameter outComp = new SqlParameter("@Completed", SqlDbType.VarChar,10){ Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                SqlParameter outName = new SqlParameter("@DisplayName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                SqlParameter outResult = new SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.VarChar,2500){ Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };              

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "GetAssessment";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssessmentName", lblAsse.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", 2);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(outScore);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(outComp);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(outName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(outResult);
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                SScore = outScore.ToString();
                SName = outName.ToString();
                SResult = outResult.ToString();
                SComp = outComp.ToString();

                conn.Close();

                lblAsse.Text = SScore;`
```

Output :

```
@Score
```

What can possibly be wrong with me or my code. Please help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to read out the actual **values** from your output parameters:

```
 SScore = outScore.Value;
```

The `.ToString()` doesn't return the value - it returns the name of the parameter instead...

See the [MSDN documentation on `SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that as well, obviously get the error can't convert object. Converted it to string, but then I nothing displays even though I insert data every time. Do you think it is maybe the way I get output parameters? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

just need to do this.
Before getting the output parameters you must close the Data reader as

```
    reader.Close();
```

and then you get output parameters as

```
    SScore = outScore.Value.Tostring();
```

for more help consult this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971497

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

**>Try this its working fine for the multiple output parameter:**

```
     using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStringEndicia"].ConnectionString)){

            using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("endicia.credentialLookup", sqlConnection))
            { 

                sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountNumber", accountNumber);
                SqlParameter outLogin = new SqlParameter("@login", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(outLogin);
                SqlParameter outPassword = new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(outPassword);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string login, password;
                login = outLogin.Value.ToString();
                password = outPassword.Value.ToString();                        
            }
        }
```