# How can i return a Varchar2 out of my stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

When I run my program I get this error in my catch

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PLS-00905: object DBI304134.FINDFREEBARCODE is invalid
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

This is the c# code I use:

```
string freeBarcode = null;

    try
    {
        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["P4connection"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connection))
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("FindfreeBarcode", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            OracleParameter outpuparameter = new OracleParameter("outpuparameter", OracleDbType.Varchar2,100);
            outpuparameter.ParameterName = "FREEBARCODE";
            outpuparameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(outpuparameter);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            freeBarcode = Convert.ToString(outpuparameter.Value.ToString());

            if (freeBarcode == null)
            {
                freeBarcode = null;
            }

            else
            {
                freeBarcode = Convert.ToString(outpuparameter.Value.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        freeBarcode = null;
    }

    return freeBarcode;
```

And this is the stored procedure i use:

```
create or replace procedure FindfreeBarcode
   (FREEBARCODE out VARCHAR2)
is
begin
   select b.BARCODE
    INTO FREEBARCODE
    from GAST g,BARCODECHECK b 
    WHERE g.GASTID(+) = b.GASTID and b.GASTID is null and ROWNUM <= 1;
END FindfreeBarcode;
```

Comment: I think you might have the '(+)' on the wrong side of the comparison. Either that or the following comparison (`b.GASTID is null`) should be `g.GASTID is null`. Which table in this query is supposed to always have data, and which will not have data if a barcode is not in use? Rewriting this query using ANSI-style joins would help clarify intent.

Answer (score 0):

Find my answer on this page

[Stored procedure output parameter returns @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626386/stored-procedure-output-parameter-returns-value)

had to change

```
freeBarcode = Convert.ToString(outpuparameter.Value.ToString());
```

to:

```
Convert.ToString(outpuparameter.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the original version of your stored proc, and change

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("FindfreeBarcode", con);
```

to

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("FindfreeBarcode(:FREEBARCODE)", con);
```

Share and enjoy.